# Expresso Store, using quantity with if/else

Tags: expresso-store

Simple question, but I can't seem to find the documentation to do this properly.

Currently using the following: `{order_qty} ITEMS IN BAG`

How would I go about replacing "ITEMS" with "ITEM" when the quantity equals 1?

Comment: Did you tried to use PHP at that case?

Comment: I don't feel comfortable writing PHP from scratch, but thanks for the lead. I'll do some googling.

Comment: Remember to enable PHP for that particular template when you will test it

Comment: `{if {order_qty} == 1}ITEM{if:else}ITEMS{/if}` worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save a bit of processing by using a simple conditional instead of an advanced conditional.

**EDIT**
Show something different when the cart is empty

```
{exp:store:cart}
 {if no_items}
   Your cart is empty!
   {!-- this only shows when the cart is empty --}
 {/if}
  {order_qty} ITEM{if {order_qty} > 1}S{/if} IN BAG
  {!-- this will only show if there is actually something in the cart --}
{/exp:store:cart}
```

Comment: I haven't tested, but it seems this would display "0 ITEM IN BAG", right?

Comment: Indeed it would, I have edited my comment with a no results conditional so you can show a customized response when the cart is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
{if {order_qty} == 1}ITEM{if:else}ITEMS{/if}
```